# Why do middle school and high school chemistry classes teach students that electrons are little balls?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

When I was in high school, I took two chemistry courses. The first was very elementary and didn't attempt to move beyond the picture of electrons, protons, and neutrons as little balls essentially. But in the second course I took (AP Chem), already confusion existed about waves vs particles and what exactly we mean by matter. And, in retrospect, I think jumping from thinking about localized particles  to waves is hard because it turns out neither description is complete enough.

I recently started studying quantum field theory and I feel like quantum fields are a lot more intuitive than delving into the whole wave-particle duality hubbub. The idea that particles are excitations of a field seems far more natural because one can envision waves and particles as excitations. Anthony Zee's book Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell draws an analogy between quantum fields and mattresses. But the point is that I definitely think young people can imagine fields as easily as little balls. Yet there's a huge difference in how easily these initial intuitions allow you to navigate the physical sciences. 
For instance, the idea of quantum fields would naturally lead students to wonder about how classical fields work.  Furthermore, for some particles, we can't define a wave function (eg photons). This becomes confusing because the wave function, at least to me, seem like the "thing" that told me how the states of a piece of elementary matter is evolving. But how can something evolve if it has no wave function?

I don't mean we have to throw out the idea of particles as little balls. The beauty of fields is that you can keep that description as a particular type of excitation. So it would complement all the tools and tricks chemists want young students to learn (eg Lewis dot structures) but give them a much clearer picture about the nature or what a particle is and ultimately I think provide a better backdrop for eventually delving deeper into the deeper questions about how quantum mechanics works exactly. This would probably help because, when they get to college, they wouldn't have to switch from an already engrained mindset. The one they would have would be more or less correct.

Maybe I am ignorant and missing something, but to me, although a bit bold, it might make more sense to introduce quantum fields earlier.

Comment: Not something I'm completely familiar with but I think this qualifies as [particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics) and may be better suited on [SE: Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also just an opinion here, teacher's use concepts that are appropriate for specific age groups. As you get older more complicated concepts can be introduced.

Comment: I think Chem SE is the right place. The classes I want to improve were my chem classes. I don't expect them do quantum field theory problems. But the stories told, metaphors used, analogies given and explanations could be more clear and accurate using quantum fields.

Comment: Also, the way qft is currently taught, it is clearly too advanced. But I have noticed education depends on development of teaching resources. Maybe if more people took this view, it would become easier to teach.

Comment: @StanShunpike While your belief that it's more intuitive to look at more quantitiave models and using wave equations to describe electrons, it's more to do with how current education systems are. After all, physics is usually taught last after chemistry and biology when it should be first. Additionally, the very nature of QM is unsettling and a lot goes against intuition, and such effects are not readily observeable at macroscopic levels.

Comment: I guess the crux of the issue is always when teachers gloss over the time-independent hamiltonian and go directly into orbitals and VSEPR theory. Rarely do teachers take multiple QM classes. Even fewer truly understand the material. My 2 cents.

Comment: I went to one of the best high schools in America. It has been consistently ranked in the top 10 for the last decade and more. Yet our chemistry teacher literally learned stuff the weekend before presenting it to the class. VSEPR. Learned it over the weekend; presented to us during the week. Lewis structures. Redox. Etc.
Now in college, I have chemistry professors who readily admit to me that calculus is much too beyond them. How can you expect them to grasp and make sense of higher level chemistry? The best they can do is maybe teach qualitative molecular orbital theory.

Comment: But we have another road block - they don't want to. Some of them just don't believe in quantum mechanics. Yes, I've had many who readily admitted that to me too. There are multiple problems at hand.

Comment: @Dissenter Maybe I just have a distorted view. I had very qualified high school teachers. And college as well. I just thought it would trickle down, but if people are that sketchy about it then it definitely isn't going to happen. The weekend before, really?

Comment: I'm a high school chemistry teacher, and I introduce the idea of electrons through the history of atomic theory (though they've all seen electrons since middle school, of course.)  Electrons start as little balls (Thomson's model) but we get to them as objects that are better described by quantum mechanics.  Working through the math of a simple situation (a particle in a box, for instance) doesn't do anything to improve students' understanding of the subject, and conceptually, it's difficult to do more than talk about the Uncertainty Principle and some of the other really big ideas.

Comment: @JasonPatterson Huh, okay. Well maybe this answers the question then. In short, the ball model is taught because it's the best most people can handle while still being usefully accurate.

Comment: @StanShunpike I would love to be able to go further into QM with my students, but even my AP Chem kids just don't have the math (or time) to do any of it numerically.  That said, you can't really discuss something like an electron orbital without referencing QM to some degree.  I would be sorely disappointed if my students left my class thinking that electrons were actually little balls.

Comment: Wouldn't this be an awesome topic for chat? I think that whatever wrong notion teachers teach students about quantum chemistry, either the simulation of orbits around atom or this case, is to make them understand their lesson. Teachers maybe leave it for some other time for students to correct their mistaken belief.

Comment: One of my little projects is to offer visualization of orbitals and electron density as volumetric clouds instead of surfaces, e.g. http://davidlonie.blogspot.com/2011/07/vtkchemistry-now-with-electrons.html   The benefit is that it's self consistent with QM but conceptually easier than going through all the math. The challenge as others have mentioned is that high school and even college instructors don't always keep up on improved educational techniques.